# Animation doesn't render

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

Whenever I try to render my animation, the render looks like this.[image]

(note: it hasn't finished rendering)

And it's supposed to look like this

[image]

Notice there is no change

Can't upload the file because it's too big but I usually reply to posts that ask for more information within an hour.

If you help, I'll give a Ferarri IRL for free :D

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out. I was using a cube to show the camera where to focus and I forgot to turn it off in the render. The white thing in the render is just the cube.